# Painting 2 different Frames using paint methods in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

I am trying to create 2 different JFrames in Java. One frame displays shapes which are uncolored 
(just the outlines) while the other frame has the colored shapes. My issue is painting the 2nd (colored) frame and how I can call a different paint method to match this other frame. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Shapes extends JFrame
{
    double diameter;
    double radius;    

    public Shapes()
    {
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }       

    public void getDiameter()
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the diameter of the circle?");
        diameter = Double.parseDouble(input);
        radius = diameter / 2;    
        /** ignore this stuff
        double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);          
        double circum = Math.PI * diameter;
        double square_enclosing = diameter * diameter;
        double square_enclosed = 2 * (radius * radius);         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The diameter of the circle is " + diameter + "\nThe radius of the cricle is " + radius + "\nThe area of the cirlce is " + area + "\nThe circumference of the circle is " + circum);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the smallest square enclosing this circle is " + square_enclosing + "\nThe area of the largest square enclosed in this circle is " + square_enclosed);
        */          
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        Shapes app = new Shapes();
        app.getDiameter();
        app.setVisible(true);
        Shapes app2 = new Shapes();
        app2.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics canvas)
    {
            double inner_square_side = Math.sqrt(2 * ((radius) * (radius)));
            canvas.drawRect(50,  50, (int)diameter, (int)diameter);
            canvas.drawOval(50, 50, (int)diameter, (int)diameter);
            canvas.drawRect((int)(50 + (.1475 * diameter)), (int)(50 + (.1475 * diameter)), (int)inner_square_side, (int)inner_square_side);
    }

    public void paint2(Graphics colored)
    {
            double inner_square_side = Math.sqrt(2 * ((radius) * (radius)));
            colored.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            colored.drawRect(50,  50, (int)diameter, (int)diameter);
            colored.drawOval(50, 50, (int)diameter, (int)diameter);
            colored.drawRect((int)(50 + (.1475 * diameter)), (int)(50 + (.1475 * diameter)), (int)inner_square_side, (int)inner_square_side);
    }       
}
```

Any ideas on how to paint another Jframe using a separate painting method? Thanks.

Comment: You should consider using a JPanel or JComponent and overriding paintComponent() for more flexibility.

Comment: -1, Why are you reposting this question (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721612/trying-to-draw-a-circle-in-java-using-variable-in-parameters). You were given good advice in that posting which you have not followed. So you are wasting everybodys time by asking the same/similar question. Until you design you program properly you will continue to have many painting issues. We do not have the time to keep repeating ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your `paint()` and `paint2()` methods is that in the second one you also have the line `colored.setColor(Color.BLUE)` which is missing in the first.

Therefore you can just put everything in `paint()` and create a parameter on the `Shapes` class that determines whether you want to set the color or not:

```
public class Shapes extends JFrame {
    private double diameter;
    private double radius;
    private boolean drawColored;

    public Shapes(double diameter, boolean drawColored) { // Parameters in constructor
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.drawColored = drawColored;

        this.radius = diameter / 2;
    }

    // Made this static and have it return the diameter the user entered
    // I also renamed it because in Java methods starting with 'get' are usually getters
    public static double promptDiameter() {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the diameter of the circle?");
        return Double.parseDouble(input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double diameter = promptDiameter();
        Shapes appUncolored = new Shapes(diameter, false);
        appUncolored.setVisible(true);
        Shapes appColored = new Shapes(diameter, true);
        appColored.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics canvas) {
        double inner_square_side = Math.sqrt(2 * ((radius) * (radius)));
        if (drawColored) {
            canvas.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        canvas.drawRect(50, 50, (int) diameter, (int) diameter);
        canvas.drawOval(50, 50, (int) diameter, (int) diameter);
        canvas.drawRect((int) (50 + (.1475 * diameter)), (int) (50 + (.1475 * diameter)), (int) inner_square_side,
                (int) inner_square_side);
    }
}
```

Note that I also moved the responsibility of prompting the user for a diameter out of the `JFrame` into the main method. I did this because we want the user to set a diameter once and then display multiple JFrames with shapes of the same diameter.

Now the `JFrame` has the `diameter` and the `drawColored` parameters. Therefore you can now create multiple JFrames with different behavior.

**Be careful:** If the difference in behavior was bigger than just "setting a color or not" you should probably create multiple classes though!

Comment: -1 `Therefore you can just put everything in paint()` This is terrible painting advice. This is NOT how custom painting is done. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do this.

Comment: Oops. I'm not very familiar with Swing and thought this was just a matter of understanding oop